# Should I add multiple secondary indexes to search

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have a search screen on my app where the users can use up to 4 parameters to search.
I have written a stored procedure to facilitate the search.

```
Select 
    ID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    CountryCd,
    State,
    Zip,
    Data1,
    Data2,
    Data3
From 
    Customer
Where 
    ((FirstName like @paramfname) OR (@paramfname IS NULL) )
    AND ((LastName like @paramlname) OR (@paramlname IS NULL))
    AND CountryCd = @paramcountry
    AND ((Zip = @paramzip) OR  (@paramzip IS NULL))
```

I have added one secondary index that includes the 4 columns `FirstName, LastName, CountryCd` and `Zip`.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Cust_FN_Ctry] 
ON [dbo].[Customer]([FirstName] ASC, [LastName] ASC, [CountryCd] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
```

My question: is this one index enough for efficient search ?

If the user runs a search by using only `FirstName` and `Country`, does SQL Server know
how to use the index efficiently?

Or do I need to add 4 separate secondary indexes on each of these columns?

Thanks

Comment: Without `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` those `OR` conditions are going to kibosh any index use quite effectively anyway. See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: How many rows are you anticipating in [dbo].[Customer]?

Comment: @Edward: i currently have 3 million rows in it. And i dont have a Join statement in my sql. Its a straight query from the Customers table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends.  If as in your example the users do a search for just the firstname and country then the index will be used.  Let's say your user does a search by zip.  At that point SQL may do a scan on your index (generally faster than a table scan) but an index starting with ZIP would be much faster.

The problem is every index you add increases your write time.  Generally adding indexes is a balancing act between the increased write time caused by an additional index and the benefit of the index on reads.  If for example this is a table where there are tons of writes all the time you may want to be careful with your indexes.  If on the other hand it's a read only table then you can be less careful.

I recently added a very large index to a table on a query that is only being run once a day.  However that particular query is very important to my business and HAD to go faster.  So the additional cost of the index wasn't as important as the increased speed of the query.

If I had to guess from your question I would say that this search is going to be run frequently.  Given that this is your only index on the table you might add additional indexes with LastName first and another with Zip first.  Initially I wouldn't bother with an index starting with CountryCd because it isn't going to be all that selective and so probably not as useful. If on the other hand you find users querying on CountryCd alone frequently then you may have to add it later.

After your system has been running with the new indexes for a bit then you should check the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` DMO to confirm that the index are in fact being used.

Comment: Index update times are mostly negligible, compared to workload caused by lack of proper indices. The above code is anyway not good for performance, as I wrote in the other answer, so fixing that, and adding more, correct indices is more important than to worry about index update times.

Comment: Actually in a high transaction environment the update time can be very important as you will note in any number of books on performance tuning.  4 indexes probably isn't a problem, 40 probably is.

Answer (score 2):

That index **can** help only for queries searching the properties in the given order. However, this help would still be spoiled with the given code! This is a typical example for beginners' mistakes when working with databases.

It can help if you search for:

*FirstName*

*FirstName, LastName*

*FirstName, LastName, Country, ZIP*

It can NOT help for search on:

*Country, ZIP*

*LastName, Country, ZIP*

because SQL Server would have to iterate through all first names and last names and, from there, look for country and ZIP. In the second case, it would still have to go through all FirstNames. Likely, a full table scan will be the lesser evil then.

For good performance, you will have to create an index on at least each of your possible search parameters/columns, probably followed by others (a single column index may help little for many different queries, a multi-col index a lot for few or just one parameterization).

**A stored procedure is completely useless here!** All modern DBMS "remember" the same SQL query if it is being sent repeatedly - make sure you use @parameters and not value literals concatenated into an SQL string (that's an error and security risk todays)! An equal SQL string (parameters remain equal, even if their submitted values vary) will cause the previous query plan to be re-used, saving much database resources.

Your "one query for all" will seriously harm performance, even with good indices. It generates one query plan which is anything but optimal for individual parameter settings! For example, SQL Server will only decide once which index to use - and not use another, proper index when parameterization changes. Optional parameters in "OR @param is null" style are a disaster for performance, since they make the best selection strategy completely unpredictable.

LIKE queries can be another problem. Full literals are o.k., a wildcard at the end also (LIKE 'Hunting%'), but querying with a starting or with enclosing wildcards ('%ington', '%ingt%') makes index usage impossible, at least for the column searched this way. If you really can't avoid using leading wildcards, put the name parts at the end of indices on Country and ZIP, so the full text scan can at least be limited to these!

My advice is: Remove that stored procedure and create dynamic, parameterized SQL in your application. You will get a maximum number of 16 different queries, all in the DB server's query cache, as fast as stored procedures, but optimized for each individual parameterization.

Comment: Just to address the first part of your answer, you are thinking specifically of index seeks.  Index scans can still be considerably faster than a table scan.  Searching on LastName, FirstName might end up not using the index, but it also might use the index using an index scan.

Comment: I can indeed use 16 different queries since i am using .Net and i can formulate the query based on user input and execute it. But regarding creating index , i am not fully clear.did you mean create 4 separate index, on 4 separate fields and the what do you mean by "probably followed by others" ?

Comment: @Kenneth Fisher: True if the main table is very broad, the _Data_ columns and others are big, like nvarchar(4000/max) columns. Or if the index can restrict the search, such as an index on country and the names, or country, zip, names, with a restriction on the first.

Comment: It doesn't really need to be all that broad.  If it happens to tip the number of rows per page (index vs data) enough to make up the difference for the extra lookup read then it may end up going with the index scan regardless.  This is particularly true if the index can help with the restriction even if the value being restricted is not the first in the index.  You may very well be correct most of the time but be careful with generic decisions.  "It depends" is so common for a reason.